# Sqlite3 update query not working in ios app

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I am trying to update one of my table's column upon button click.

The issue is that code isn't giving any exception still it is not updating the table.

When the view controller load again , it shows the old value rather then updated one.

Code for update db is attached below.

```
@try {
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *sqlStatement = @"UPDATE messagesTable SET Favorite = 1 where MessageID=";
        sqlStatement = [sqlStatement stringByAppendingString:msgId];

        NSLog(@"sql statement: %@", sqlStatement);



        const char *sql = [sqlStatement UTF8String];
        int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);
        if(result != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Prepare-error #%i: %s", result, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }

                   // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }


    sqlite3_close(database);


}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@",exception.name);
    NSLog(@"Reason: %@",exception.reason);

}
@finally {

}
```

Any suggestions are welcome. :-)

Comment: This is a simple problem to solve.  If the sqlite functions aren't returning `SQLITE_OK` then report the error message returned from `sqlite3_errmsg()`.  That's what it's there for, to tell you what went wrong.

Comment: Yep, there's no real point in catching exceptions from SQLite calls.  Everything is done with return codes and error codes.

Comment: Yes, as Hot Licks states; the sqlite API is based on C, not Objective-C, so where does it say that it will throw Objective-C exceptions (or C++ exceptions for that matter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not calling `sqlite3_step`, which performs the update. After the `sqlite3_prepare` and before the `sqlite3_finalize`, you need something like:

```
if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE)
    NSLog(@"%s: step error: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
```