# Update Data Into SQLite Database

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I want to update the data into sqlite db.I tried and followed lot of links and methods for update data.But all these do not work out for me.

when i insert my data, following data inserted in db with no problem.

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT  INTO BusinessCardAppOneTable (NamorTitofImginTxtFld ,TxtofTxtView ,ImaGe,Location,Date,Time)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?);"];
```

***NOTE:For image i created the image folder(path) in DB.***

Then i fetched and i displayed these data from DB to tableview.

Then i edited NamorTitofImginTxtFld,TxtofTxtView,Date,Time (These are in edit view controller-where i get the image,location,date,time,NamorTitofImginTxtFld,TxtofTxtView from tableview(fetch data))

After that i edited NamorTitofImginTxtFld,TxtofTxtView,date and time.Also if i want to set the date and time i should go to `REMAINDER VIEW CONTROLLER`(from remainder button of edit view controller to remainder view controller).Where i set the date and time picker.Once i set that and back to edit view controller i can see the edited part.

So my update query is

```
NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE BusinessCardAppOneTable SET NamorTitofImginTxtFld = ?,  TxtofTxtView = ?,Date = ?   WHERE  Time =?  "];
```

If i only edited  NamorTitofImginTxtFld and TxtofTxtView,these only updated in db.But if i edited all NamorTitofImginTxtFld , TxtofTxtView with date and time all these do not  update.

Anyone can explain about the database update and how to update these 4 columns in db successfully?

Comment: Perhaps you can share how you're binding values to your `?` placeholders. Are you using `sqlite_bind_xxx` functions or using something like FMDB (which simplifies the process)? BTW, the `stringWithFormat` syntax is not needed (or desirable) in this case.

Comment: yes i use sqlite_bind_text

Comment: help me rob.I did not get anything.

Comment: I'd look at [`sqlite3_changes`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html) to see how many rows were updated. If zero, then it must not have matched the `WHERE` clause of your SQL. Or perhaps there was an error in the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` (I assume you're checking that return code to make sure you got `SQLITE_OK`). I'd also check the `sqlite3_step` return code, to make sure you got `SQLITE_DONE` for that, too. It's hard to see what the problem could be on the basis of what's been provided thus far.

Comment: where means match the fields?

Comment: Your `UPDATE` statement has a `WHERE` clause for which you're updating rows where the `Time` is equal to some value. If, after calling `sqlite3_step` on that statement (after binding the values, of course), you're not seeing any change in the database, I would suspect that `sqlite3_changes` would have returned `0`. That could happen if the `sqlite3_bind_xxx` for column number `4` (the `Time` column) did not match a value in your table (or if there was some other SQL bug). There are far too many possible sources of that sort of problem for us to diagnose without seeing more code.

Comment: sqlite3_bind_text(fstatementone, 1, [getAllDetails.txtfldstrOne UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
  sqlite3_bind_text(fstatementone, 2, [getAllDetails.txtviewstrOne UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(fstatementone,3,[getAllDetails.strDateOne UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT); sqlite3_bind_text(fstatementone,4,[getAllDetails.strTimeOne UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

Comment: Rob this is my update sqlite_bind_xxxx query see that above.

Comment: Those bind statements look OK (though you might want to (a) log the values to confirm they are returning what you think they are; and (b) check the return codes of _all_ SQLite calls. You may want to update your question with a more complete code sample, as the problem is not apparent from what has been provided thus far. The devil is in the details, and we don't have enough to divine the problem. And when you looked at `sqlite3_changes`, what did it report?

Comment: Yes rob i checked with  int tc = sqlite3_changes(mydatabase);
     NSLog(@"total count of updated rows are ==%i",tc);

Comment: Also in console part i am getting 2014-05-06 10:33:19.403 BusinesscardApp[635:70b] total count of updated tasks are ==0

Comment: if i updated only textfield and textview,in console part                     2014-05-06 10:37:35.996 BusinesscardApp[727:70b] total count of updated rows are ==1

Comment: You seem reluctant to update your question with a slightly more complete code sample, and until you do, neither I, nor anyone else, can do anything to help you in the absence of that. You need to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your code is too complicated, then create a simplified rendition that exhibits the problem you describe. Unless we can reproduce your problem, we can't help you solve your problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52076/discussion-between-user3182143-and-rob)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted the 3 various options

first   `//it match up ur answer`

```
update BusinessCardAppOneTable set NamorTitofImginTxtFld = ?, TxtofTxtView = ?, Date = ?,  Time =?    where id = 5   // here u need to identify your id, if it is correct it surely update
```

second     `//it is related to your answer`

Yes You can use Parametrized Query as Below :-

```
NSString *sqlString = @"update BusinessCardAppOneTable set NamorTitofImginTxtFld = ?, TxtofTxtView = ?, Date = ?,  Time =?    where id = ?";

sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
if(sqlite3_prepare(database, [sqlString UTF8String], -1, &amp;stmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
{
  //Handle Error
}


if(sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [record.name UTF8String],[record.type UTF8String],[record.state UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK)
{
  // Handle Error
}
if(sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, record.key) != SQLITE_OK)
{
  // Handle Error
}


if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE)
{
  // Handle Error
}
```

And your Parametrized Code is ready.

in third choice

u follow the link [Sqlite3 update query not working in ios app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319591/sqlite3-update-query-not-working-in-ios-app/17320311#17320311)

Comment: U must pass your id , otherwise it does not match up your records

Comment: if u need additional information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050281/sqlite-is-not-updating-my-database-ios